# Setting Text Styles in Xcode (6.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, accessibility

How to set text styles in iOS 6? How do I set a font ("Futura 30pt" for example) as the default font for "body"?

---

(additional info)

In this dialog box:

[image: Text Styles XCode]

there is a label that says "Text Styles." I am assuming that this is how you can re-use font styles, but perhaps I am mistaken?

If this is wrong, how do I set a text style (for example: like you have h1, h2, body in css, and you can re-use these declarations elsewhere). How do you set a re-usable text style in Xcode? I'm trying to create a typographic system.

Comment: (1) What do you mean "the default font for "body""? (2) iOS 6? Really? Really?

Comment: I added some details above. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "text styles" and "body" you are talking about Dynamic Type and its "body" style (`UIFontTextStyleBody`), as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFontTextStyleBody), then the problem is that you have not understood what Dynamic Type is about. The whole point of Dynamic Type is that the font and size used are not up to you; they are up to the system (and the user's text size preferences). By using Dynamic Type, you are accepting the system's choice of font.

If you want to set a font as Futura 30pt, then *set* it. This has nothing to do with any "styles". If you want to set *all* UILabel fonts as Futura 30pt, you can use the `appearance` proxy. But there is no built-in "styles" system (unless you design one yourself somehow); this is not a web browser.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I am using Storyboard and trying to set re-usable type styles. For example, a style for "button," a style for "header," etc. In the font dropdown in Storyboard there is a label that says "Text Styles" (as in the screenshot I added above), and I'm assuming that a "Text Style" is a ... for lack of a better description ;-) ... a text style. If this is not how you set up a text style, then how?? Thanks for your patience with my lack of familiarity in XCode.

Comment: You were not unclear. (Well, you sort of were, but I guessed correctly what you meant.) :) Those are the Dynamic Type fonts. And what I'm telling you is: you do not get to set what fonts they are. My answer includes a link to the documentation on Dynamic Type. Please click that link and read the documentation I've pointed you to! It tells you what Dynamic Type is all about.

Comment: In other words, to the extent that there is a "style" system in iOS, this is it, and you don't get to pick the fonts. For anything else, you just have to keep saying what fonts you want. Of course in many circumstances you can use the `appearance` proxy to help. But that would be a different question. I believe I have answered the question you did ask.

Comment: Ok thanks! Just to clarify, there is no way to set up a font style such as in css (`h1 { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif}; `)? There is no way to structure obj-c or swift code to accomplish this? Thanks a ton for your patience with a newb.

Comment: But you are just making me repeat myself. No, there is no css. This is not a web browser. But your code can set the font of all labels, say, using the `appearance` proxy.

Comment: Can you give me one tiny code snippet of how to set all labels using the `appearance` proxy?

Comment: Sure. What language would you like this tiny code snippet to be in?

Comment: I'm using Obj-C. I really appreciate your support!!

Comment: You would say, for example (very very early in the life of your program) `[[UILabel appearance] setFont: f];` where `f` is the UIFont you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone coming here later should check out:

https://github.com/tombenner/nui